# TwoSum function in R

Tags: r, function

I was trying to create a function that will pick up the 2 numbers in a list which have the sum of a target number.

Can someone let me know why my code isn't working?

Thank you!

```
TwoSum <- function(num, target) {
  for (i in 1:length(num) - 1) {
    for (j in i+1:length(num)) {
      if (num[i] + num[j] == target) {
        print("the numbers are:")
        print(paste0(num[i], num[j]))
        a <- a - 1
      }
    }
  }
  if (a == 1) {
    print("No pairs")
  }  
} 

a <- 1
num <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
target <- 7

TwoSum(num,target)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... I still got the error Error in if (num[i] + num[j] == target) { : argument is of length zero...

Answer (score 3):

You should not use a loop for this. Use `combn` instead:

```
combs <- combn(num, 2)
combs[,colSums(combs) == target]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    3
#[2,]    5    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Introduce braces in the second and third line.

```
TwoSum <- function(num, target) {
  for (i in 1:(length(num) - 1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):length(num)) {
      if (num[i] + num[j] == target) {
        print("the numbers are:")
        print(paste0(num[i], num[j]))
        a <- a - 1
    }
  }
```